# Really slow field creation or deletion

Tags: fieldtype, fields

I have an issue with creating and deleting field types ,its takes a really long time to do both and sometimes the site times out and when I get back in the field is only half created.I can then save the field again and it will take around 3 minutes to process through the database. 
At the end of the day i can create a field but it is taking too long and I want to know whats going on with the database that is causing that delay .I am running EE 2.9.2 and have no other issues with EE as everything else runs fast.
Thanks in advance for any help or advice

Comment: How large is your database? Also, how many rows and columns are in your exp_channel_data table?

Comment: And what's your hosting situation?

Comment: I have dug a little more and it seems to relate to my database size , i have 10,000+ entries and looking at the mysql  process the slow down seems to stem from the the actual size of the database.The new fields I add are created properly but there is a around a two minute delay in the process. Im not sure if there is anything that can be done about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I decided to update  to the latest version 2.11.1 and i was looking through the change logs and I saw this on the 2.10 change log

*Added -Optimized queries used in new channel field creation.*

So I went ahead with the upgrade and it has greatly improved the field creation time